# insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext: failed to assign persitentStore

Tags: ios, core-data

After starting to work with configurations (hence more than one store files) the managed object context save operation failed due to missing persistent store file information for newly inserted objects.

Apple states under `assignObject:toPersistentStore:`:

> It is only necessary to use this method if the receiver’s persistent store coordinator manages multiple writable stores that have object’s entity in their configuration. Maintaining configurations in the managed object model can eliminate the need for invoking this method directly in many situations. If the receiver’s persistent store coordinator manages only a single writable store, or if only one store has object’s entity in its model, object will automatically be assigned to that store.

So I understand that as long as a given entity is **only** assigned to one configuration (one store file) it is automatically assigned to the correct store.

If I inspect the coordinator for its persistentStores it lists the 2 available stores.  Inspecting the models `entitiesForConfiguration:` I can see that the entities have been correct assigned to either configuration.

But if I inserted an object into the model look for the persistent store via `[[managedObject objectID] persistentStore]` its always `nil`?

Do I missed something/somewhere?

---

At least this problem could be solved. I've put category(and an explanation) on my site for everyone who feels to be considered.
[A category on NSEntityDescription along with an explanation.](http://berndrabe.de/blog)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a persistent store bound to the default configuration.
I use a setup like yours but only bind one persitent store to custom configuration 1 and another one to custom configuration 2. So there is no store for the default configuration.

With this setup I never had a problem with objects not being assigned to a store.

Comment: No I haven't. Could you elaborate more on you specific configuration. I separated the model to have store files on different locations inside the bundle. One in the document folder with automatic iCloud backup and another one inside Library/Application Support/ marked with from Backup excluded file attribute.